Are both of these sentences correct in American English?
Someone asks you two personal questions and then they add:

You don't have to answer either of the questions.
You have to answer neither of the questions.

Are these correct and do they mean the same thing?

I'm not a native AmE speaker, but it's misleading for this question to imply that "correct" might mean something different here for AmE, BrE, or whatever. At this relatively primitive level, English is English, and example #2 above is syntactically perfectly "correct". But it would rarely be used by any native Anglophones, both because it's clumsy and because it's ambiguous (it could mean must not or need not answer either or both questions).


Doesn't make sense, you must not answer none of the questions...? It's all the same in American and British English it's more likely to be any of the… except some Brits might say "You needn't answer any of the questions


With regard to the pair of sentences your offer, this AmE speaker can’t see any reason to distinguish between my dialect and BrE. In any event, the You have to answer neither version is awkward at best.

Sorry but most of the time there are zero differences between AmE and BrE in regular grammar situations. This is one great example of that. [Yes, 2 is wrong in both]. Just because Brits can say "you needn't answer all the questions" does not mean they don't use "you don't have to x".

This question is salvageable, but you should add information about where the sentences came from and why you think they might be right or wrong. It's okay to tell us you're speaking American English, but it's not necessary or appropriate to assume only Americans can help you.

Both sentences are grammatically valid, but the meanings are different. The second one means that the person is entirely forbidden to answer. Consider the difference between "you don't have to eat anything" and "you have to eat nothing."
By the way, it's rather off-putting to try to forbid users from answering. Stack Exchange has the whole voting system to let you act against answers you feel are incorrect (and moderators to delete them if they're outright inappropriate). But many speakers of other dialects can answer more knowledgeably about my dialect than I can. In fact, many people for whom English is a second language know more about it than I do!
But this question is a very basic one and has nothing to do with any dialect. Moving the negation from "have to" to "neither" has the same effect in any variety of English, and many users with skills above basic should be able to answer competantly.
